# plotting datetime along the x-Axis

Tags: csv, datetime, numpy, matplotlib

Hi There i'm trying to plot a datetime array on the x axis. However i seem to have a problem with actually plotting them and keep getting a value error of:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '2013-02-18 00:00:00'
```

Does anyone have any ideas where i'm going wrong?

The data itself is formatted in four columns and when printed looks like this: ('04/03/2013', 7.0, 12.0, 17.0) ('11/03/2013', 23.0, 15.0, 23.0).

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
data = np.genfromtxt('H:/AppliedGIS/Python/AssignmentData/GrowthDistribution/full.csv', names=True, usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3), delimiter= ',', skiprows=1, dtype =[('Date', 'S10'),('HIGH', '<f8'), ('Medium', '<f8'), ('Low', '<f8')])
print data
x =  [foo[0] for foo in data]
y =  [foo[1] for foo in data]
y2 = [foo[2] for foo in data]
y3 = [foo[3] for foo in data]
print x, y, y2, y3
dates = []
for i in x:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime['i', '%d/%m/%Y']
    dates.append(date)

pl.plot(data[:, dates], data[:, y], '-r', label= 'High Stocking Rate')
pl.plot(data[:, dates], data[:, y2], '-g', label= 'Medium Stocking Rate')
pl.plot(data[:, dates], data[:, y3], '-b', label= 'Low Stocking Rate')
pl.title('Amount of Livestock Grazing per hectare', fontsize=18)
pl.ylabel('Livestock per ha')
pl.xlabel('Date')
pl.grid(True)
pl.ylim(0,100)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I immediately see two problems in the code.

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime['i', '%d/%m/%Y'] should be
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('i', '%d/%m/%Y')

pl.plot(data[:, dates], data[:, y], '-r', label= 'High Stocking Rate')

Try this instead:
pl.plot_date(dates, y, '-r', label= 'High Stocking Rate')
```